# Not able to update database using checked rows in gridview in c# ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, checkbox, sql-update

I'm trying to promote students from previous class to a new one. For this I'm using a `gridview` with `checkboxes` to select the students and update only selected student details in the database with the new class.

The problem is that when I click promote only the first row details is getting updated to new class and the rest are not. Even though I'm using `foreach` so that all the selected students get updated.

my output looks like this:

[image: Output]

my table after promotion:

[image: Database Table after promotion]

Here is my aspx markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type = "text/javascript">
function checkAll(objRef)
{
    var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0;i<inputList.length;i++)
    {
        //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
        var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        if(inputList[i].type == "checkbox"  && objRef != inputList[i])
        {
            if (objRef.checked)
            {
                //If the header checkbox is checked, check all checkboxes
                inputList[i].checked=true;
            }
            else
            {
                //If the header checkbox is unchecked, uncheck all checkboxes
                inputList[i].checked=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var TargetBaseControl = null;

   window.onload = function()
   {
      try
      {
         //get target base control.
         TargetBaseControl = 
           document.getElementById('<%= this.GridView1.ClientID %>');
      }
      catch(err)
      {
         TargetBaseControl = null;
      }
   }

   function TestCheckBox()
   {              
      if(TargetBaseControl == null) return false;

      //get target child control.
      var TargetChildControl = "chkPromote";
      var TargetChildControlAll = "chkboxSelectAll";

      //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
      var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

      for(var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
         if(Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl,0) >= 0 && Inputs[n].checked || Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControlAll, 0) >= 0 &&
            Inputs[n].checked)
          return true;        

      alert('Select at least one student!');
      return false;
   }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>Student Promotion
        <small>Administrator</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Student Promotion</li>
            </ol>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <div class="box box-danger">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Student Promotion Manager</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Select Standard You Wanna Promote</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpclass" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpclass_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow: scroll; height: 200px">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive"
                                GridLines="None">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="checkmobilenumbers"  runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPromote" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="checkmobilenumbers" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No.">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnPromote" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClientClick="javascript:return TestCheckBox();" Text="Promote Selected Students" OnClick="PromoteSelectedStudents" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is my c# code behind:

```
protected void PromoteSelectedStudents(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (drpclass.SelectedIndex.ToString() != "0")
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                //if eligible start promote process                    
                CheckBox chkRow = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPromote");
                //bool isSelected = (row.FindControl("chkPromote") as CheckBox).Checked;
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    string nowDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365).ToString();
                    string classdrp = drpclass.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    //Int16 clsupdt = Convert.ToInt16(classdrp + 1);
                    string Student = row.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
                    string dateCreated = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "update studentregistration set class = (Select promotable_to from addclass where classname = '" + classdrp + "'), LastPromotedOn = convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 103), NextPossiblePromotion = DATEADD(year, 1, NextPossiblePromotion) where class = '" + classdrp + "' and name = '" + Student + "'";
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        message = "Selected Students are promoted to the new class & the next promotion date is: " + nowDate;
                        script += message;
                        script += "')};";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message From St.Joseph", script, true);
                        ga.bindClassDropDown(drpclass);
                        GridView1.DataSource = "";
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message.ToString()) + "')</script>");
        }
    }
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stjosephconnect"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ Your code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: To fix the problem at hand you need to do some debugging. Put in some break points and examine what your code is doing. You also should put your connection inside a USING statement. If you get an error at the database your connection will be left open.

Comment: I added breakpoints and checked but the flow of the execution was normal. I checked each statement line by line while I was debugging.

Comment: Are the values changing? There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that is jumping at me that would cause the behavior you are describing.

Comment: ya, only the first row of the gridview is getting updated in the database

Comment: OK. So look at the values in your update statement. Are they correct? Is it running more than once? I can't really do much from here. This is pretty basic debugging you need to on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the first row you are resetting `GridView1` data source inside the loop `GridView1.DataSource = ""; GridView1.DataBind();` if you need to reset it do that outside the loop after finishing all students update.

```
if (i > 0)
{
    message = "Selected Students are promoted to the new class & the next promotion date is: " + nowDate;
    script += message;
    script += "')};";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message From St.Joseph", script, true);
    ga.bindClassDropDown(drpclass);
    // Below two lines are the issue you need to remove them or move them outside foreach
    GridView1.DataSource = "";
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```